# Testing Mocked object constructor

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I'm trying to test an object "SqlGymSessionRepository" that takes an int on initialization. If no parameter is supplied I want it to throw an error. I can't figure out how this should work. I have something like this:

```
[TestMethod]
[ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentNullException))]
public void Throw_Exception_If_Not_Session_Id()
{
    var mockRepos = new Mock<SqlGymSessionRepository>();
}
```

I'm unsure of where the constructor should be tested?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't want to mock the class (implementation) you're testing.  You want to mock dependencies on a class.  If you're testing `SqlGymSessionRepository` then you don't want a mock of it, you want its implementation.  The mocking is for any other classes on which `SqlGymSessionRepository` depends, which you would then supply to it for your tests.

Call the constructor directly.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to test the constructor, call it:

```
new SqlGymSessionRepository(null);
```

---

**Update** per the comments:

You are stating that it takes a nullable int. Then the compiler will ensure that it will always get called with either `null` or an integer value. If `null` is an invalid initialization valid, your code should throw an exception and you can test that. You don't need to test that the method gets called without a parameter. C# is statically typed, so code won't compile unless a value is provided for all required parameters.

Comment: The problems is that because the object requires an int, I'm unable to create it with a null thus testing the excpetion, as there's a compile time error?

Comment: How does the code in the constructor look like ? If the constructor takes an int, you can't pass in null, so no need to test for that. If it takes int?, you can pass in null and test that.

Comment: It just takes none nullable int. I'm concerend that it could get called without the int. In this case, rather than write an exception, should I just let it throw the system error?

Comment: If null is an invalid initialization valid, your code should throw an exception and you can test that. - That's what I'm trying to achieve. How would I do that? If I add null then it wont compile to be tested.

Answer (score 0):

```
new SqlGymSessionRepository(null);
```